MIDI clock sync and then decouple
I have a Native Instruments Maschine MK3 and an old Yamaha QY-70 sequencer I'd like to use for live performance. What I'd like to do is play a project on the Maschine, and then handover to the QY-70 while I load the next project. This is to prevent dead air between songs and buy me some time in case of laptop crashes etc.
The Mk3 and QY-70 will MIDI clock sync and start/stop together nicely, but if the next project is at a different BPM then the QY-70 will suddenly change tempo when the new project loads which I don't want. I'll use the mixer to fade out the QY-70 when the MK3 is ready.
Is there a neat way to initially sync but then ignore clock signals? I've been playing about with writing Python scripts to manage the handover but wanted to check there wasn't an easier way. Also, if I'm making things too hard for myself with this approach to the dead air problem then let me know.
Many thanks

This is just speculation, so not really an answer, but too long for a comment.
You can't sync just "initially", MIDI Clock sync needs constant tempo corrections all the way to the end of the song. Every MIDI Clock pulse, 24 pulses per beat, causes a tiny tempo change in the slave, that's the idea of the protocol. If you only sync and tempo-correct for awhile at the start, timing will start to drift off immediately.
Does the Maschine keep sending MIDI clock while loading the next project? If it does and you want the QY70 to ignore that clock input, you'll have to somehow tell the QY70 to ignore the clock input. If the Maschine stops sending MIDI clock and the QY70 still continues to play, then you can disconnect the MIDI cable to prevent the tempo change when the new Maschine project is loaded.
One way to do an automatic sync switch could be a MIDI clock proxy between the Maschine and the QY70. For example an Arduino/Teensy box with a MIDI input and output. The clock proxy would keep track of incoming tempo, relay it to the QY70, and then automatically switch to its own internal clock source when the Maschine starts loading a new song. How the proxy could detect this: either by explicit control command like a MIDI note or control-change from the Maschine, or by detecting a large-enough discrepancy between the incoming clock and its internal clock from which it sends clock ticks out. That is, IF the Maschine stops sending MIDI clock when loading.
Another alternative would be to use a separate MIDI clock master that's independent of the Maschine and the QY70, and make the Maschine a clock slave. Can it be a MIDI clock slave?

That all makes sense, thank you. Both devices work in slave mode. I was toying with adapting a Python program like https://github.com/ElliotGarbus/MidiClockGenerator to act as the master clock. I could then code the BPM changes and start signals between songs. I hadn't considered the proxy device idea; will look into it.

@AlanCash Could the QY70 be the clock master? Or another hardware MIDI clock generator. Something like a Novation Circuit Tracks could do the job as well, and provide better sounds than the QY70. ;)

Good idea. I tried using the QY-70 as the clock master but I'd then have to stop it to change the BPM before starting the new project on the Maschine, ending up with the same dead air problem (it's hard to do anything quickly on the QY-70, especially with no backlit screen!). Do you have any experience/ recommendations for dedicated midi clocks?

@AlanCash Only ones I've built myself, and a Ploytech tap tempo pedal. Usually a MIDI clock generator is a part of a sequencer. Your idea of doing a tempo change with a fade with no audible silent gap essentially means two different clocks running at different rates at the same time. Or a coordinated instantaneous tempo-change and playback start. MIDI clock tempo changes may not be perfectly instantaneous, if there's averaging to smooth out jitter. The QY70 seems to be more of a problem than a solution. How about trying something else? Or how about, put everything in the same Maschine project?
